# Detect WebBrowser complete page loading

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I detect when a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control has completed loading?

I tried to use the Navigate and DocumentCompleted events but both of them were raised a few times during document loading!

Comment: How are you using c#? Is this an asp.net question, or are you using the web browser control?

Comment: @kibibu i am using the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Comparing the AbsolutePath may not work if the page has many frames. I tried that way before but haven't succeeded yet. I'm still stuck with this problem. :( :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the `DocumentCompleted` event will get fired for all child documents that are loaded as well (like JS and CSS, for example). You could look at the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` in `DocumentCompleted` and check the Url property and compare that to the Url of the main page.

Comment: That's what I figured out from fighting this problem myself.  I was getting a bunch of extra completions on things like ad banners.  I discard any event that doesn't match the URL I'm after and it works.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel i'm affraid to say there are 3 problems with this approach. first, when ur parent (top level) url does a server side url redirect, the url of the document u r trying to compare to changes. secondly, there's the situation of a frame and the parent page having the same url which change behaviour on other parameters like referrer etc so url is same. also, client-side redirects - they occur AFTER you think the page has loaded and webbrowser control returns "all is good to go". if you want help on how to reduce these, let me know & i can provide an answer here.

Comment: @Paul Kearney - pk feel free to read my last comment to Loren.

Comment: Shooting from the hip - but i would bet money on scripts not firing documentloaded - as they do not have a DOMDocument 'attached'. It is probably frames, since a html segment that contains framesets technically have windows embedded in windows - thus multiple documents

Answer (score 31):

I did the following:

```
void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
    return; 

  //The page is finished loading 
}
```

The last page loaded tends to be the one navigated to, so this should work.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328835/why-is-webbrowser-documentcompleted-firing-twice/2331827#2331827).

Comment: Perfect - just what I needed. Explains why sometimes the whole page was appearing, and sometimes only the partial page.

Comment: Just change it to ((WebBrowser)sender).Url ;-)

Comment: Not really work.
The problem is that there are facebook and twitter content, and the main problem is if the page load content via js with ajax. Everything in the documentReady event.

Comment: How to call it? I tried call it `BrowserDocumentCompleted(sender, e);`

Comment: @vanloc The name doesn't matter. You just need to assign it to the DocumentCompleted event of the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 19):

The following should work.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if page is fully loaded or not
    if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        return;
    else
        //Action to be taken on page loading completion
}
```

Comment: Quite helpful & simple!

Comment: In my application, the event is fired at least four times

Comment: @JackGriffin That's because every iframe is also a document and hence will fire the event. It's tricky to do this. You could check Urls as mentioned by Paul in the answer above, but this can also fail, as described by  Erx_VB.NExT.Coder. If URL's that are to be opened fall within a certain predefined URL set, you might know how to avoid these. 
For example, when i first faced this problem, I knew what URLs will be opened so I created a child class of WebBrowser class and added some additional information to it. Then, it was easy  ( by prompting the sender object) to do this.

Comment: @Transcendental I see the problem. Kyle's solution worked for me, but maybe I've been just lucky :-).

Comment: Me too. My app fires every two times.

Answer (score 13):

Note the url in DocumentCompleted can be different than navigating url due to server transfer or url normalization (e.g. you navigate to www.microsoft.com and got http://www.microsoft.com in documentcomplete)

In pages with no frames, this event fires one time after loading is complete. In pages with multiple frames, this event fires for each navigating frame (note navigation is supported inside a frame, for instance clicking a link in a frame could navigate the frame to another page). The highest level navigating frame, which may or may not be the top level browser, fires the final DocumentComplete event.

In native code you would [compare the sender of the DocumentComplete event to determine if the event is the final event in the navigation or not](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180366). However in Windows Forms the sender parameter is not wrapped by WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs. You can either [sink the native event](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx) to get the parameter's value, or check the [readystate property of the browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate.aspx) or [frame documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752602(VS.85).aspx) in the DocumentCompleted event handler to see if all frames are in the ready state.

There is a prolblem with the readystate method as if a [download manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618(VS.85).aspx) is present and the navigation is to a downloadable file, the navigation could be cancelled by the download manager and the readystate won't become complete.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue of multiple `DocumentCompleted` fired events and tried out all the suggestions above. Finally, seems that in my case neither `IsBusy` property works right nor `Url` property, but the `ReadyState` seems to be what I needed, because it has the status 'Interactive' while loading the multiple frames and it gets the status 'Complete' only after loading the last one. Thus, I know when the page is fully loaded with all its components.

I hope this may help others too :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to trigger DocumentCompleted/Navigated events for external Javascript or CSS files, but it will for iframes. As PK says, compare the WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs.Url property (I don't have the karma to make a comment yet).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WPF there is a `LoadCompleted` event.

If it's `Windows.Forms`, the `DocumentCompleted` event should be the correct one. If the page you're loading has frames, your `WebBrowser` control will fire the `DocumentCompleted` event for each frame (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180366) for more details). I would suggest checking the `IsBusy` property each time the event is fired and if it is false then your page is fully done loading.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DocumentCompleted event with a page with multiple nested frames didn't work for me.

I used the Interop.SHDocVW library to cast the WebBrowser control like this:

```
public class webControlWrapper
{
    private bool _complete;
    private WebBrowser _webBrowserControl;

    public webControlWrapper(WebBrowser webBrowserControl)
    {
        _webBrowserControl = webBrowserControl;
    }

    public void NavigateAndWaitForComplete(string url)
    {
        _complete = false;

        _webBrowserControl.Navigate(url);

        var webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser) _webBrowserControl.ActiveXInstance;

        if (webBrowser != null)
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete += WebControl_DocumentComplete;

        //Wait until page is complete
        while (!_complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    private void WebControl_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        // Test if it's the main frame who called the event.
        if (pDisp == _webBrowserControl.ActiveXInstance)
            _complete = true;
    }
```

This code works for me when navigating to a defined URL using the webBrowserControl.Navigate(url) method, but I don't know how to control page complete when a html button is clicked using the htmlElement.InvokeMember("click").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event ProgressChanged ; the last time it is raised will indicate that the document is fully rendered:

```
this.webBrowser.ProgressChanged += new
WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(webBrowser_ProgressChanged);
```

Comment: How would you know when it is the last time called?