# Source code to text file not working using C#.net and Web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, screen-scraping

This source code scraping is not working; it's giving a blank text file as output:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.jigsaw.com/SearchCompany.xhtml?opCode=refresh&rpage=20&order=0&orderby=0&industry=1160000&subindustry=1160300&country=9000&country=2000&cmDead=false&count=0&screenNameType=0&screenName=&omitScreenNameType=0&omitScreenName=&rowsPerPage=200&uid=13473859&tok=1354716874406-8761960955252771794");

    string MainsourceCode = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("G:/jigsaw_info.txt", true);
    sw.Write(MainsourceCode + "\n");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting to write too fast. You should wait `DocumentCompleted` event.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.jigsaw.com/SearchCompany.xhtml?opCode=refresh&rpage=20&order=0&orderby=0&industry=1160000&subindustry=1160300&country=9000&country=2000&cmDead=false&count=0&screenNameType=0&screenName=&omitScreenNameType=0&omitScreenName=&rowsPerPage=200&uid=13473859&tok=1354716874406-8761960955252771794");
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      File.WriteAllText("G:/jigsaw_info.txt",webBrowser1.DocumentText);    
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear, Do u want me to move all the above code in those braces? sorry i'm new to coding. please help

Comment: `private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("URL");

            string MainsourceCode = webBrowser1.DocumentText;


    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      File.WriteAllText("G:/jigsaw_info.txt",webBrowser1.DocumentText);    
}   
        }
    }

}`

Comment: @SantoshKumar You sould attach to event before `Navigate` See my new code above. It works.

Comment: @SantoshKumar That's all I can do. I gave a full working code. I hope you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until navigation is complete.  Navigation is asynchronous.

[Detect WebBrowser complete page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777878/detect-webbrowser-complete-page-loading)