# How do I know if my webbrowser finished loading the all page

Tags: c#, html, .net, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect WebBrowser complete page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777878/detect-webbrowser-complete-page-loading)

How do I know if my webbrowser finished loading all the page?

how can I display multiple pages in a successive but I do not have the right to go if a page have not completely downloaded on C#

Comment: this is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Answer (score 1):

To detect when a WebBrowser control has completed loading, once I've used this code:

```
void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
  {
      return; 
  }

   //Page Loading Finished
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it did not function at 100% of the time it works and sometimes not I do not know why sometimes it does not wait the end of the page load: s