# C# .NET webbrowser control in separate thread raising event on main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, webbrowser-control

I need to scrape a lot of pages in paralel, while my UI thread must not be blocked. I am creating thread for each page (url) and instantiateing webBrowser control in that thread to execute javascript and get html after that. When the webBrowser gets the html I m raising event on UI thread to register that browser has done its job, beacuse I want to know when all the browsers have fetched html so I can merge all the data and display it.

**1.)The first probem is, some threads never raise an event so I'm stuck waiting.**

**2.)The second problem is I cant dispose browser without causing external browser to fire**, allways pulling the rug beneath the browser so he decides to continue by opening page in users default browser I guess. But if not disposing at all, I m running out of ram.

I v been searching around, found a lot of related stuff but I fail to implement it for my use case. Here s my code:

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void ThreadFinishedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);
        public event ThreadFinishedEventHandler threadFinishedEvent;
        int threadCount = 0;
        int threadReturnedCount = 0;
        List<string> linksGlobal;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            threadFinishedEvent += new ThreadFinishedEventHandler(OnThreadFinished); 
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scrapeLinksWithBrowsersInSeparateThreads();
        }


        private void scrapeLinksWithBrowsersInSeparateThreads()
        {
            linksGlobal = getLinks(); //10 urls all the same -> https://sports.betway.com
            threadCount = linksGlobal.Count;

            Random rand = new Random(123);
            int waitTime = 0;//trying not to be registered as DOS attack or smth
            foreach (string url in linksGlobal)
            {
                runBrowserThread(url, waitTime);
                waitTime += rand.Next(500, 3000) + 500;//each browser will start navigating withing 1 - 4 seconds interval from each other
            }
        }



        public void runBrowserThread(string url, int waitTime)
        {
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler completed = null;
                    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

                    completed = (sndr, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sndr as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                        {
                            wb.DocumentCompleted -= completed;
                            string html = (sndr as WebBrowser).Document.Body.InnerHtml;

                            threadFinishedEvent.Raise(this, EventArgs.Empty); // I have EventExtension allowing me this

                            //wb.Dispose(); //whenever and wherever I put this it causes external browser to fire
                            // Application.ExitThread();  //this sometimes seems to cause event never firing, not shure
                        }

                    };

                    wb.DocumentCompleted += completed;
                    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

                    Thread.Sleep(waitTime); //tryin not to get registerd as DOS attck or smth, each browser will start navigating withing 1 - 4 seconds interval from each other
                    wb.Navigate(url);
                    Application.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
        }


        private void OnThreadFinished(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            threadReturnedCount++; // i get this for smth like 3 - 5 out od 11 threads, then this event stops being raised, dunno why
            if (threadReturnedCount == threadCount)
            {
                // Do work
                //this never happens cos a lot of threads never raise event, some do
            }

        }



        private List<string> getLinks()
        {
            List<string> links = new List<string>();

            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");
            links.Add("https://sports.betway.com");

            return links;
        }
      }
```

P.S. returnign data from threads is separate problem, I did not implement it yet but first I want to solve this. I will use objectFactory which will be called from each thread like Factory.createObject(html), I will have to use some kind of locking on that Factory since it will be located on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find clean solutions to problems presented in my question. I did try some things and I did get some results, but that was not good enough. I will review my question and explain what I did in the end to solve my problem.

**1.)The first probem is, some threads never raise an event so I'm stuck waiting.**

Answer 1: Still not shure what was happening here, but this got alot better after I (kinda) solved the second problem

**2.)The second problem is I cant dispose browser without causing external browser to fire**

Answer 2: Now this can be done by using ActiveXInstance of web browser control, you ll need to include SHDocvW dll into your project. 
Check Frank_FC's answer here
[Detect WebBrowser complete page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777878/detect-webbrowser-complete-page-loading)

There were also memory leak problems with webBrowser control. Using google I found out how I can reduce this problems (there is a lot of info on that).

In the end, the whole thing was not very stable, memory leaks stil happened, I would get out of memory exceptions, unpredictable behaviour, bad performance (slow page loadings) etc. etc. And the code was just ugly and everything seemed just... not the right way to do things. **Do not use webBrowser control if you want to scrape a lot of pages in short time. Do not instantiate dozens of invisible webBrowser controls each in her own thead and expect to handle all the events efficiently.**

**What did I do in the end ?**
Had a beer with my friend he showed me his program which he made as college task. Java program developed in Eclipse using JSoup package for scraping web. 2 functions in Java, each function 10 - 20 lines of code and he got 100 times faster, simpler, better solution then mine. You just say getHtml(url) and JSoup gets it for you, does not matter if page runs javascript or anything, crazy.

So now my .NET app is firing java app which writes html in text files on disk and when it's finished .NET app collects the data, cycling this over and over again.

Spent 100+ hours fiddling with webBrowser control and then in 2 hours time made immeasurably better solution. **Choose your tools wisely ! Java + Eclipse  + JSoup seems much better way to go for scraping/crawling than .NET**