# How to get a content of a page that updates too often using webbrowser in C#

Tags: c#, html, dynamic, web-crawler, webbrowser-control

I would like to get the latest content of a page that updates too often, for example, https://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/ (prices update every five second on weekdays)

I am using the following code:

```
        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/");

        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        string myData = webBrowser.DocumentText;
```

But that does not return me the latest info as shown in the page.  Eventually I would like to re-parse that page and get the latest data a few minutes/seconds later.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably caching the result.  Try webBrowser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4tye44(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do not think that is the issue, all I need is to load after the JScript runs, but I have no clue how to get it done.  Any other idea?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777878/detect-webbrowser-complete-page-loading