# Does .NET webbrowser.stop() function fire DocumentCompleted event?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I use the webbrowser control of .NET to open piles of urls,and the loop is called in the DocumentCompleted event.

Now I want to control the timeout.So I use a timer,and when timeout it will stop the webbrowser using the stop() function.

The question is: it seems that the stop function fires the DocumentCompleted event **sometimes**.So if the timer calls the next loop after stop the webbrowser,error happens.And if it doesn't call the next loop,sometimes the loop will be stopped in the middle.

The procedure like this(codes not related are deleted):

```
private string[] urls;//urls are stored here
private int index = 0;//next url index
private void loopFunc()
{
    timer.Enabled = true;
    wb.navigate(urls[index]);
    index++;
    return;
}

private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    loopFunc();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wb.stop();
    //loopFunc() or not?
}
```

I don't know for sure whether it fires the event or not,and I found nothing via google.

Comment: As i remember DocumentCompleted has a really strange behaviour. This helped me solved my issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328835/why-is-webbrowser-documentcompleted-firing-twice .

Comment: @plurby:Multi-thread is my suggestion.But,also some strange behaviors.

Comment: FYI, the WebBrowser control has nothing to do with C#. It is part of .NET, not part of C#.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your situation clearly this could solve your problem:

```
Timer On --->  loopFunc() --> goto url --> oncomplete -> start timer again -->
                  |
                  |---> Stop timer so it doesn't call loopFunc again
```

So stop the timer after `loopFunc`, when the download completes, `loopFunc` is called again:

```
private void loopFunc()
{
    timer.Enabled = true;
    wb.navigate(urls[index]);
    index++;
    timer.stop(); //<<<<<
    return;
}
```

And your tick should be:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  loopFunc();
}
```

Then start your timer again on document complete:

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 wb.Stop();
 timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: The exception "resource is in use" may occur using this way. wb.stop() can avoid this exception,and that's I am using the stop function.

Comment: @Rusty Updated answer. So maybe call `wb.Stop()` on `documentcompleted` ?

Comment: If wb.stop fires the DocumentCompleted event,can't there be errors?

Comment: @Rusty Are you sure `stop` calls the `DocumentCompleted` method?

Comment: At least sometimes.I tested it.