# Getting HTML body content in WinForms WebBrowser after body onload event executes

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control, onload

I have a WebBrowser control in WinForms whose URL property is set to an external webpage. I also have an event handler for the DocumentCompleted event. Inside this handler, I'm trying to get specific elements, but wb.Document.Body seems to capture the HTML before onload is executed.

```
{System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement}
    All: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection}
    CanHaveChildren: true
    Children: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection}
    ClientRectangle: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1200 Height = 0}
    Document: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument}
    DomElement: {mshtml.HTMLBodyClass}
    ElementShim: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.HtmlElementShim}
    Enabled: true
    FirstChild: null
    htmlElement: {mshtml.HTMLBodyClass}
    Id: null
    InnerHtml: "\n"
    InnerText: null
    Name: ""
    NativeHtmlElement: {mshtml.HTMLBodyClass}
    NextSibling: null
    OffsetParent: null
    OffsetRectangle: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1200 Height = 0}
    OuterHtml: "<body onload=\"evt_Login_onload(event);\" uitheme=\"Web\">\n</body>"
    OuterText: null
    Parent: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement}
    ScrollLeft: 0
    ScrollRectangle: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1200 Height = 0}
    ScrollTop: 0
    shimManager: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShimManager}
    ShimManager: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShimManager}
    Style: null
    TabIndex: 0
    TagName: "BODY"
```

`"<body onload=\"evt_Login_onload(event);\" uitheme=\"Web\">\n</body>"` is the pre-JavaScript content. Is there a way to capture the state of the body tag after `evt_Login_onload(event);` executes?

I have also tried using `wb.Document.GetElementById("id")`, but it returns null.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how it can be done, I've put some comments inline:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool complete = false;
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate
    {
        if (complete)
            return;
        complete = true;
        // DocumentCompleted is fired before window.onload and body.onload
        this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
        {
            // Defer this to make sure all possible onload event handlers got fired
            System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate 
            {
                // try webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id") here
                MessageBox.Show("window.onload was fired, can access DOM!");
            }, null);
        });
    };

    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com");
}
```

**Updated**, it's 2019 and this answer is surprisingly still getting attention, so I'd like to note that my recommended way of doing with modern C# would be using `async/await`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303).

Comment: +1 I can confirm this answer worked for me, though I had no need of using `SyncronizationContext.Current.Post()` because I'm running single threaded.

Comment: @StevendeSalas, the whole purpose of `SyncronizationContext.Current.Post` was to return from the `onload` event handler and continue asynchronously on the same UI thread (so any possible exceptions wouldn't be thrown inside the MSHTML code firing the event). The code has evolved a bit since then to use `async`/`await` instead, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643/1768303).

Comment: I tried a similar approach- but didn't work.. Can you take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697987/form-become-blank-intermittently?

Comment: @Lijo, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303. Visit all links listed there.