# How to update a object WebBrowser after a ajax update

Tags: c#, ajax, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I need to access a page and save two pages of this site.

but when I try to save pages, saves 2 times the same page.

follows the code

```
namespace sadfesrgshtydgf
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Completado(WebBrowser b)
    {
        while (b.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && b.Document.Body == null)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
    }
    int Pagina = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

        //Completado(webBrowser1);        
    }




    public string diretorio;

    public void interfaceUsuario()
    {

        diretorio = @"C:\Users\klima\Desktop";
        criarArquivo();
    }

    public void criarArquivo()
    {
        try
        {
            //var documente = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

            var documente1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("grd_voos").OuterHtml;

            //Determino o diretorio onde será salvo o arquivo
            string nome_arquivo = diretorio + "\\Infraero.txt";

            //verificamos se o arquivo existe, se não existir então criamos o arquivo
            //if (!File.Exists(nome_arquivo))
            File.Create(nome_arquivo).Close();

            // crio a variavel responsável por gravar os dados no arquivo txt
            arquivo = File.AppendText(nome_arquivo);



            //Escrevo no arquivo txt os dados contidos no textbox
            arquivo.Write(documente1);


            //Posiciono o ponteiro na próxima linha do arquivo.
            arquivo.Write("\r\n");

            //  MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Fecho o arquivo

            arquivo.Close();
        }
    }

    public void interfaceUsuario1()
    {

        diretorio = @"C:\Users\klima\Desktop";

        criarArquivo1();
    }


    public TextWriter arquivo;

    public void criarArquivo1()
    {
        try
        {



            var documentus = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("grd_voos").InnerHtml;

            //Determino o diretorio onde será salvo o arquivo
            string nome_arquivo = diretorio + "\\Infraero1.txt";

            //verificamos se o arquivo existe, se não existir então criamos o arquivo
            // if (!File.Exists(nome_arquivo))
            File.Create(nome_arquivo).Close();

            // crio a variavel responsável por gravar os dados no arquivo txt
            arquivo = File.AppendText(nome_arquivo);



            //Escrevo no arquivo txt os dados contidos no textbox
            arquivo.Write(documentus);


            //Posiciono o ponteiro na próxima linha do arquivo.
            arquivo.Write("\r\n");

            //  MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Fecho o arquivo

            arquivo.Close();
        }
    }

    private void NavegarPagina0()
    {

        HtmlElement combo;
        combo = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aero_companias_aeroportos");
        combo.SetAttribute("value", "SBKP");
        HtmlElement botao = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar");
        botao.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").Focus();
        botao.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").InvokeMember("click");
        Pagina++;

    }

    private void NavegarPagina1()
    {



        HtmlElementCollection doc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28].Children[0].Children[0].All;
        HtmlElement a = doc[2].Children[0];

        interfaceUsuario();
        a.InvokeMember("click");
        Completado(webBrowser1);
        Pagina++;





    }

    private void NavegarPagina2()
    {

        webBrowser1.Refresh();

        while(Convert.ToString( webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28].Children[0].Children[0] ) != "1"){



        }

            MessageBox.Show("Nop while");


        Completado(webBrowser1);



        interfaceUsuario1();

        Close();


    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {



        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            //webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

            Completado(webBrowser1);
            if (Pagina == 0 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar") != null)
                NavegarPagina0();
            else if (Pagina == 1 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28] != null)
                NavegarPagina1();
            else if (Pagina == 2 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28] != null)
                NavegarPagina2();

        }

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


} }
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta...

Comment: entao, eu tenho que acessar a pagina, entrar automaticamente nas voos e pegar a informação na tabela de voos na pagina 1 e 2, porem a segunda pagina é atualizada via ajax

Comment: ja sim, eu consigo salvar a primeira pagina, porem quando ele vai salvar a segunda ele salva a primeira novamente

Comment: Você trabalha aonde ?

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentComplete` can be fired more than once if the page uses frames/iframes. A more reliable way is to use DOM `window.onload` event, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18573522/1768303) it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  namespace sadfesrgshtydgf
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Completado(WebBrowser b)
        {
            while (b.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && b.Document.Body == null)
            {
                webBrowser1.Refresh();
                Application.DoEvents();

            }
        }
        int Pagina = 0;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

            //Completado(webBrowser1);        
        }




        public string diretorio;

        public void interfaceUsuario()
        {

            diretorio = @"C:\Users\klima\Desktop";
            criarArquivo();
        }

        public void criarArquivo()
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Error: Por favor desligue o seu computador ");
            try
            {
                //var documente = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

                var documente1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("grd_voos").OuterHtml;

                //Determino o diretorio onde será salvo o arquivo
                string nome_arquivo = diretorio + "\\Infraero.txt";

                //verificamos se o arquivo existe, se não existir então criamos o arquivo
                //if (!File.Exists(nome_arquivo))
                File.Create(nome_arquivo).Close();

                // crio a variavel responsável por gravar os dados no arquivo txt
                arquivo = File.AppendText(nome_arquivo);



                //Escrevo no arquivo txt os dados contidos no textbox
                arquivo.Write(documente1);


                //Posiciono o ponteiro na próxima linha do arquivo.
                arquivo.Write("\r\n");

                //  MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Fecho o arquivo

                arquivo.Close();
            }
        }

        public void interfaceUsuario1()
        {

            diretorio = @"C:\Users\klima\Desktop";

            criarArquivo1();
        }


        public TextWriter arquivo;

        public void criarArquivo1()
        {
            try
            {



                var documentus = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("grd_voos").InnerHtml;

                //Determino o diretorio onde será salvo o arquivo
                string nome_arquivo = diretorio + "\\Infraero1.txt";

                //verificamos se o arquivo existe, se não existir então criamos o arquivo
                // if (!File.Exists(nome_arquivo))
                File.Create(nome_arquivo).Close();

                // crio a variavel responsável por gravar os dados no arquivo txt
                arquivo = File.AppendText(nome_arquivo);



                //Escrevo no arquivo txt os dados contidos no textbox
                arquivo.Write(documentus);


                //Posiciono o ponteiro na próxima linha do arquivo.
                arquivo.Write("\r\n");

                //  MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Fecho o arquivo

                arquivo.Close();
            }
        }

        private void NavegarPagina0()
        {

            HtmlElement combo;
            combo = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aero_companias_aeroportos");
            combo.SetAttribute("value", "SBKP");
            HtmlElement botao = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar");
            botao.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").Focus();
            botao.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").InvokeMember("click");
            Pagina++;

        }

        private void NavegarPagina1()
        {



            HtmlElementCollection doc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28].Children[0].Children[0].All;
            HtmlElement a = doc[2].Children[0];

            interfaceUsuario();
            a.InvokeMember("click");
            Completado(webBrowser1);
            Pagina++;





        }

        private void NavegarPagina2()
        {

            webBrowser1.Refresh();

            while(Convert.ToString( webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28].Children[0].Children[0] ) != "1"){



            }

                MessageBox.Show("Nop while");


            Completado(webBrowser1);



            interfaceUsuario1();

            Close();


        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {



            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                //webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

                Completado(webBrowser1);
                if (Pagina == 0 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar") != null)
                    NavegarPagina0();
                else if (Pagina == 1 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28] != null)
                    NavegarPagina1();
                else if (Pagina == 2 && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[28] != null)
                    NavegarPagina2();

            }

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    } }
```

Comment: This code does '[busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)', eating CPU cycles in the `while` loop. Also, `Application.DoEvents()` effectively organizes a nested message loop here, which may cause reentrancy and generally is a [bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx).