# How to do something once webbrowser document has loaded

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

How can I run some stuff in a subroutine only when a specific URL has been completely loaded in a vb.net webbrowser.

e.g.

```
sub button click

webbrowsernavigate to whatever

(This is what I need)if document has loaded statement
do stuff

end sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [tag:vba] or [tag:vb.net]?

Comment: You could use `async/await` for this if targeting .NET 4.5. I don't have a VB.NET sample ready, but [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18573522/1768303) to do it in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class has a [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event that you can bind to:

> Occurs when the `WebBrowser` control finishes loading a document.

The MSDN article has an example which demonstrates how you can use this event effectively:

```
Private Sub PrintHelpPage()

    ' Create a WebBrowser instance.  
    Dim webBrowserForPrinting As New WebBrowser()

    ' Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads. 
    AddHandler webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted, New _
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PrintDocument)

    ' Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = New Uri("\\myshare\help.html")

End Sub 

Private Sub PrintDocument(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim webBrowserForPrinting As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)

    ' Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Print()
    MessageBox.Show("print")

    ' Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to do it in a similar way to the code in my question?

Comment: @BenHoldenCrowther Probably but I wouldn't recommend it. The `WebBrowser` control is asynchronous, so it won't block the UI while it's loading. Using events like this is a *much* more elegant way of handling it that simply blocking the whole application while you wait for a document to download.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do it in a similar way to in my question? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: the webbbrowser control raises BeforeNavigate2 and other events from a background thread. If those events are blocked by your waiting code, the navigation won't happen.