# EventHandle.WaitOne + WebBrowser = Deadlock when waiting for DocumentComplete

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, deadlock, manualresetevent

I've got a Problem with the automatisation of WebBrowsing in an C#-Program.
I've used the code before for a BHO and there it was working. 
But within a pure c# Program there seems to be some kind of deadlock. I've instructed my program to click on a search button and then wait (via a manualresetevent) for documentcomplete to signal. But now it seems that the click on the search button isn't processed until the ManualResetEvent signals a timeout. Thereafter the click is made and also the DocumentComplete-Event is fired.

For the structure of that programm:
The WebBrowser-Control is part of a WindowsForm. The WebBrowser Control is passed to a Class which runs a Thread. This Class again passed the control to another class where the concrete behaviour according to the loaded webbrowser is programmed.

So in Code this lookes this way:

1. Setup of the thread

   ```
   _runner = new Thread(runner);
   _runner.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   _runner.IsBackground = true;
   _runner.Start();
   ```
2. Processing of withingthe Runner-Method

   ```
   b.placeTipp(workStructure);
   ```
3. The PlaceTipp-Method

   ```
   public void placeTipp(ref OverallTippStructure tipp)
       {
           _expectedUrl = String.Empty;
           _betUrl = String.Empty;
           _status = BookieStatusType.CHECKLOGIN;

           while (true)
           {
               _mreWaitForAction.Reset();
               checkIETab();

               switch (_status)
               {
                   case BookieStatusType.REQUESTWEBSITE:
                       ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Keine IE-Tab vorhanden. Fordere eine an", this.BookieName));
                       //if (RequestIETabEvent != null)
                       //    RequestIETabEvent(this, new EventArgs());
                       _status = BookieStatusType.NAVIGATETOWEBSITE;
                       _mreWaitForAction.Set();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.NAVIGATETOWEBSITE:                                                
                       _webBrowser.Navigate(@"http://www.nordicbet.com");
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.CHECKLOGIN:
                       checkLogin();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.LOGINNEEDED:
                       doLogin();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.LOGGEDIN:
                       _status = BookieStatusType.SEARCHTIPP;
                       _mreWaitForAction.Set();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.SEARCHTIPP:
                       searchTipp(tipp);
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.NAVTOSB:
                       NavToSB();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.GETMARKET:
                       getMarket(tipp);
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.PLACEBET:
                       placeBet(tipp);
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.CONFIRMBET:
                       confirmBet();
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.EXTRACTBETDATA:
                       extractBetId(ref tipp);
                       break;
                   case BookieStatusType.FINISHED:
                       return;
               }


               if (!_mreWaitForAction.WaitOne(60000))
               {
                   //Sonderüberpüfung be LoginNeeded
                   if (_status == BookieStatusType.LOGINNEEDED)
                   {
                       //checkLogin();
                       throw new BookieLoginFailedExcpetion();
                   }
                   //TIMEOUT!
                   ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Timeout bei warten auf nächsten Schritt. Status war {1}", this.BookieName, this._status.ToString()));
                   throw new BookieTimeoutExcpetion(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Timeout bei dem Warten auf Ereignis", this.BookieName));
               }
           }
       }
   ```
4. The SearchTipp-Method where the Deadlock is happening:

   ```
   private void searchTipp(OverallTippStructure tipp)
       {
           if (_webBrowser.InvokeRequired)
           {
               _webBrowser.Invoke(new delegatePlaceBet(searchTipp), new object[] { tipp });
           }
           else
           {
               ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Suche Tipp {1}", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
               _expectedUrl = String.Empty;
               if (!_webBrowser.Url.ToString().StartsWith("https://www.nordicbet.com/eng/sportsbook"))
               {
                   ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Nicht auf Sportsbookseite. Navigiere", this.BookieName));
                   _status = BookieStatusType.NAVTOSB;
                   _mreWaitForAction.Set();
                   return;
               }
               _searchCompleted = false;
               HtmlDocument doc = _webBrowser.Document;

               if (doc != null)
               {

                   mshtml.IHTMLInputElement elemSearch = (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement)doc.GetElementById("query").DomElement;
                   if (elemSearch != null)
                   {
                       Thread.Sleep(Delayer.delay(2000, 10000));
                       elemSearch.value = tipp.BookieMatchName;

                       mshtml.IHTMLElement elemSearchButton = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.GetElementById("search_button").DomElement;
                       if (elemSearchButton != null)
                       {
                           Thread.Sleep(Delayer.delay(900, 4000));

                           elemSearchButton.click();
                           //elemSearchButton.InvokeMember("click");

                           if (!_mreWaitForAction.WaitOne(10000)) //Here The Deadlock happens
                           {
                               //Now the click event and therefor the search will be executed
                               ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Suche ist auf Timeout gelaufen", this.BookieName));
                               throw new BookieTimeoutExcpetion(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Suche ist auf Timeout gelaufen", this.BookieName));
                           }                                                        

                           _mreWaitForAction.Reset();
                           HtmlElement spanResult = doc.GetElementById("total_ocs_count");
                           while (spanResult == null)
                           {
                               Thread.Sleep(500);
                               spanResult = doc.GetElementById("total_ocs_count");
                           }

                           int total_ocs_count = 0;
                           if (!Int32.TryParse(spanResult.InnerHtml, out total_ocs_count))
                           {
                               ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tip {1} nicht gefunden", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                               throw new BookieTippNotFoundExcpetion(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tip {1} nicht gefunden", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                           }

                           if (total_ocs_count <= 0)
                           {
                               ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tip {1} nicht gefunden", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                               throw new BookieTippNotFoundExcpetion(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tip {1} nicht gefunden", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                           }
                           /*
                       else if (total_ocs_count > 1)
                       {
                           throw new BookieMoreThanOneFoundExcpetion(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tipp {1} nicht eindeutig", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                       }
                       */
                           ConsoleWriter.writeToConsole(String.Format("Bookie {0}: Tip {1} gefunden", this.BookieName, tipp.BookieMatchName));
                           _status = BookieStatusType.GETMARKET;
                       }
                   }
               }
               _mreWaitForAction.Set();
           }
       }
   ```

Has anybody an Idea what's happens here?

Thanks

lichtbringer

Comment: Calling WaitOne() on an STA thread is illegal by COM rules.  The CLR permits it because it is technically possible to not get deadlock if you're lucky.  No such luck available here.  The wall of irrelevant code prevents a decent workaround suggestion.  Move code to the DocumentCompleted event handler instead.

Comment: Changed the STA-bit but effectis still the same. Why should I move it in the EventHandler? From the flow of the process it fits better where it is. Why is worked when the coding was used in a BHO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `_webBrowser.Invoke(new delegatePlaceBet(searchTipp), new object[] { tipp })`, you make the `searchTipp` method be executed synchronously on the main UI thread. This is understood, as you cannot access `WebBrowser` API from any thread other than the original thread the control was created on.

However, by doing so, the `_mreWaitForAction.WaitOne(10000)` call will be too executed on the main UI thread, effectively blocking the message loop (which was started by `Application.Run`). `WebBrowser` needs a functional message loop, which is constantly pumping Windows messages, otherwise `DocumentCompleted` doesn't get fired, and you are getting a deadlock.

My understanding is, you only create another thread here to organize the workflow of your automation scenario. **You really don't need another thread for that.** [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643/1768303) of how it can be done on the main UI thread asynchronously, using `async`/`await`, and [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530) of using `WebBrowser` in a console app.

Alternatively, *as a workaround*, you can use `WaitWithDoEvents` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20876645/1768303), like this: `_mreWaitForAction.WaitWithDoEvents(10000)`. It waits for a handle while still pumping messages. You should be aware of [potential implications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/1768303) of creating a nested message loop with `Application.DoEvents()`.

Note, you still don't need a separate thread if you use a nested message loop. It will give you the linear code workflow on your main UI thread. Example:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, args) => 
            mre.Set();
        this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
        try
        {
            this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.example.com");
            mre.WaitWithDoEvents(10000);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(this.webBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml);
}
```

Although as I've mentioned above, you can achieve the same more naturally and without nested message loops, using `async`/`await`, which is a preferred way of doing this, IMO.

Comment: Well thanks, that solved it. I've also made the Thread into a async/await triggered by a timer as it is a task which is repeated every x hours.

Comment: @lichtbringer, glad it helped. With `async/await` you have a better alternative to timer: `await Task.Delay(delay)`. E.g., you can do it in a loop to perform the same task periodically.