# How to cancel async work gracefully?

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, async-await

I have a UI application which logs something every second. Every time `OpenFileHandler` is fired, I must start logging to a new file. This is a very simplified version of the code:

```
string _logItem;
string _fileName;
CancellationTokenSource _cts;
Task _task;

private void OpenFileHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // once OpenFileHandler has been fired, 
    // the _logItem should go to the new file

    if (_task != null && !_task.IsCompleted)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        // can't do: _task.Wait();
    }

    if ( _fileName != null )
    {
       _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       _task = LogAsync(_fileName, _cts.Token);
    }
}

private async Task LogAsync(string fileName, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, false))
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(_logItem);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.WriteLine("end of log!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem: `OpenFileHandler` is synchronous, but I need to make sure the pending `WriteLineAsync` has completed and the old log file has been closed, before I can start a new `LogAsync` task.

I cannot do `_task.Wait()` inside `OpenFileHandler` because it will block the UI thread.

I also cannot make `OpenFileHandler` an `async` method and do `await _task` inside it. That's because when the application is closed, and `OpenFileHandler` is fired with `_fileName` being `null`, I want the `"end of log!"` line to still be there in the log.

How do I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling a pending task synchronously on the UI thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876645/cancelling-a-pending-task-synchronously-on-the-ui-thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first line of `LogAsync`, await the old task:

```
await prevTask;
```

You somehow need to pass in the previous task. Maybe as a method argument.

You probably need to catch an `OperationCancelledException`, or:

```
await prevTask.ContinueWith(_ => { }); //suppress exceptions
```

Comment: This might be it, but how to make sure I still get `end of log!` when the the app exits? There may be no more UI message loop iterations.

Comment: Alternatives: a) keep a message loop running until the last logging task has completed. You don't need UI for a message loop. b) Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to not take a dependency on the UI at all. You probably want to `Wait` for the logging task as the last line of `Main`.

Comment: The continuation inside `AsyncLog` is queued using `WinFormsSynchronizationContext.Post`, so I have to pump messages for it to be executed when the app exits. `ConfigureAwait(false)` may indeed help, then I could possibly do `Wait()`. In my app `LogAsync` also updates UI, I'd have to use `BeginInvoke` for that if I use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: I'd say that updating the UI from that method is architecturally undesirable anyway. Consider using `IProgress` to notify the UI, or expose an event for the UI to consume.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not handle the special case of shutting the application down (and null being passed to the `OpenFileHandler` method)?

So in the case of the application shutting down then you `_cts.Cancel()` and then  `_task.Wait()` to allow the logs to complete being written.

Rather than doing a `while(true)` can't you check if the `CancellationToken` has been cancelled or not, and if it has then exit and write the 'End of Log!'

Comment: I'd loose `end of log!` then. If you do `_task.Wait()` at the shutdown, it will still result in a deadlock

Comment: Check if the CancellationToken - I don't think this would help, if I don't `await` this task after requesting cancellation, this check may not have a chance to execute.

Comment: yes, I'm suggesting that you make the OpenFileHandler async and then Cancel and then Wait for the task when you shut the application down.