# Wait synchronously for an async method to finish on the same thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, deadlock

Is there a way to wait synchronously for an async method that runs on the same thread?

The desired effect is

- to have the Worker() run asynchronously on the UI thread
- and at the same time wait for it to finish before the Close() method returns

The example below enters in a deadlock, and if I make Form1_FormClosing() async I don't satisfy the second condition.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Show();
        Worker(cts.Token); // async worker started on UI thread
    }

    async void Worker(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
        tcs.SetResult(true); // signal completition
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        MessageBox.Show("This is supposed to be second");
    }

    private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel(); // request cancel 
        tcs.Task.Wait(); // deadlock
        await tcs.Task; // button1_Click() gets control back instead of Worker()
        MessageBox.Show("This is supposed to be first");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `await Task.Delay(1000, ct).ConfigureAwait(false)`. and `tcs.TrySetResult(true);`. Make sure that any long operation performed in `Worker` is cancelable through the token. Also catch `OperationCanceledException` in the worker, and `tcs.SetCanceled()` in that case.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do?  You've said what isn't working about your solution attempt, but you haven't said what the problem is you're attempting to solve.

Comment: Do you want to have the Task continue running, or cancel it at whatever interruption point it is paused?

Comment: @BenVoigt I want to cancel it at whatever point is paused.

Comment: @Chris, check this: [Cancelling a pending task synchronously on the UI thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876645/cancelling-a-pending-task-synchronously-on-the-ui-thread)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to wait synchronously for an async method that runs on the same thread?

You don't need to synchronously wait. By making `Worker` `async Task` instead of `async void` you can get the desired behavior and remove the useless `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
private Task workerTask;
public Form()
{
     workerTask = Worker(cts.Token);
}

private async Task Worker(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
}

private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel(); // request cancel
    await workerTask; // Wait for worker to finish before closing
}
```

I'm missing the implementation of `Close()`, but i suspect you could do without it and relay on the form closing event to cancel the worker.

Comment: Close() is called by another form and when it returns Worker() must be stopped, otherwise things that are modified by the other form will crash Worker(). Alex's suggestion is what I was looking for. When I request cancel the task is instantly killed, throwing an exception, and I don't have to worry that Worker() will access things I'm about to modify.

Comment: It would only be instantly killed if you use `ct.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Are you using it somewhere?

Comment: I do not, but it makes a similar behavior to Task.ConfigureAwait(false) that Alex suggested.