# How to use DerralManager GetDeferral() in WPF Closing Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, async-await

Wpf

I am attempting to delay window closing until all tasks are completed using the
async/await library of StephenCleary https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.

The event handler delegate and event arguments definitions:

```
public delegate void CancelEventHandlerAsync(object sender, CancelEventArgsAsync e);

public class CancelEventArgsAsync : CancelEventArgs
{
    private readonly DeferralManager _deferrals = new DeferralManager();

    public IDisposable GetDeferral()
    {
        return this._deferrals.GetDeferral();
    }

    public Task WaitForDefferalsAsync()
    {
        return this._deferrals.SignalAndWaitAsync();
    }
}
```

Then in the code behind of the NewWindowDialog.xaml, I override the OnClosing event:

```
public NewWindowDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override async void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnClosing(e);
            await LaunchAsync();
        }

        private async Task LaunchAsync()
        {
            var vm =(NewProgressNoteViewModel)DataContext;
            var cancelEventArgs = new CancelEventArgsAsync();
            using (var deferral = cancelEventArgs.GetDeferral())
            {
                // a very long procedure!
                await vm.WritingLayer.CompletionAsync();
            }

        }
```

Clearly, this fails since e.Cancel = true is executed before the await. So what am I missing to correctly use GetDeferral() to delay the window closing while the tasks are being completed (in WPF).

TIA

Edit: With the help of everybody, I am currently using this. However, does anybody have a good example of the Deferral pattern on window closing?

Thanks to all.

```
private bool _handleClose = true;
        protected override async void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            using (new BusyCursor())
            {
                if (_handleClose)
                {
                    _handleClose = false;
                    IsEnabled = false;
                    e.Cancel = true;

                    var vm = (NewProgressNoteViewModel)DataContext;

                    await vm.WritingLayer.SaveAsync();

                    e.Cancel = false;
                    base.OnClosing(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `base.OnClosing(e)` after `await` (as well as setting `e.Cancel = false` prior to that), because that would be out of sequence. Too see what I mean, check out [how it's called by the Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,dee77f5097cad59d).  Your continuation after `await` would be invoked on a completely different stack frame and on another message loop iteration.

Comment: @noseration Didn't think about that...but it seems to work correctly?! (And I really don't like forcing a reentry on the same OnClosing method with Close(). ) :)

Comment: note that in the current version of your code you're still not protected from re-entrancy when user clicks on Close in the windows caption or  hits Alt-F4. Setting `IsEnabled = false` doesn't prevent that from happening. In which case, `vm.WritingLayer.SaveAsync()` would get called twice or more, with whatever side effects this may leave you with, if any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a deferral. Just set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` property to `true`, await the long-running operation and then close. You could use a flag to avoid doing the same thing more than once:

```
private bool _handleClose = true;
protected override async void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_handleClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        await Task.Delay(5000);// a very long procedure!
        _handleClose = false;
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was coming to that conclusion as well. But I would still be interested in some examples of how to use the Deferral pattern if you know of any. (Google seems very lacking on this). Thanks.

Comment: I would only add that for me, changing Close() to e.Cancel = false; base.OnClosing(e); seems to run smoother.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a more user-friendly approach to show a modal "Please wait..." message inside your `Window.Closing` event handler that goes away when the `Task` is complete. This way, the control flow doesn't leave your `Closing` handler until it's safe to close the app.

Below is a complete WPF example of how it can be done. Error handling is skipped for brevity. Here's also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20876645/1768303) dealing with a similar problem.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Task _longRunningTask;

        private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_longRunningTask?.IsCompleted != false)
            {
                return;
            }

            var canClose = false;

            var dialog = new Window
            {
                Owner = this,
                Width = 320,
                Height = 200,
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
                Content = new TextBox {
                    Text = "Please wait... ",
                    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                },
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None
            };

            dialog.Closing += (_, args) =>
            {
                args.Cancel = !canClose;
            };

            dialog.Loaded += async (_, args) =>
            {
                await WaitForDefferalsAsync();
                canClose = true;
                dialog.Close();
            };

            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        Task WaitForDefferalsAsync()
        {
            return _longRunningTask;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;

            _longRunningTask = Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, although for simplicity I used a BusyCursor. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AlanWayne, you still may want to disable the UI while showing the busy cursor to prevent users from clicking around while it's pending :)

Comment: Yes. Please see the code I settled on at the bottom of my question. It became quickly obvious that you are correct; when the close button is pressed  repeatedly strange and not good things happen. Thanks.