# WPF show indefinite progress while lengthy operation runs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to show an indefinite progress bar in a little WPF window of class `BackgroundOperationWindow` that I wrote. This is a simple window with an indefinite progress bar, but no "Cancel" button, since there is nothing to be cancelled.

It contains this method:

```
public async Task PerformAction( Action action )
{
    await Task.Run( () => action() );
}
```

and is used to show that connection to a server is in progress:

```
async void ConnectToServer( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var bo = new BackgroundOperationWindow();
    bo.Show();
    await bo.PerformAction( () =>
    {
        // This takes some time...
        Server.Connect(...)
    } );
}
```

My problem is: "ConnectToServer" shall not return until the connection is established. (Since the calling window of `ConnectToServer` is not yet visible at this time, it is no problem that it will be blocked).
All the examples that I found using async/await use some kind of "`Button_Click`" scenario, where it's OK (and intended) that `Button_Click` returns before the task is completed.

In other words: I want to get rid of the "`async`" in `async void ConnectToServer(...)`. `ConnectToServer` shall not act asynchronously from its caller's perspective.

What I'm looking for is some kind of "`Task.WaitAndKeepTheUIThreadRunningSoThatTheProgressBarAnimates()`"

Comment: It's not quite user-friendly to show a blocking modal window just to wait for an end of an async operation. If however refactoring isn't an option, I believe I have a solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510363/1768303

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to PerformAction in a Task of its own:

```
Task.Run(async () => await bo.Performan
    ...etc.
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP problem (he seems to want to run an async operation synchronously) but may potentially introduce a bunch of other issues related to [fire-and-forger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22369179/1768303).