# WebBrowser submit form, follow redirect, click URL, follow redirect automation

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to create a program that basically does the following:

- Opens a url
- Enters into the first form (web form)
- Submits and follows the form action
- Clicks a url on the next page
- then exits

So far I've tried using the event handler (DocumentCompleted) then access the form via wb.Document.Forms[0] and then using SetAttribute. That didn't work because I'm pretty much logging in so it only submitted the form (since that was under the DocumentCompleted event) at the end, after all the login info was loaded for multiple accounts (yes, I'm logging into multiple accounts). Any ideas? I'm lost. I've provided a basic example of what I tried, below. I haven't gotten as far as clicking the link on the next page because I have not yet been successful in logging in. At first I tried this with no eventhandler but then I realized it was needed or else web.Document always returned null. Then I tried adding the eventhandler in the foreach and the if statement in the function for the event. That as I said before only worked at the end and even after that I don't believe login was successful although I'm not 100% on that.

```
foreach(login in logins){
    if (web.Document != null)
    {
        var form = web.Document.Forms[0];
        var input = form.Children[0];
        input.SetAttribute("value", "input value");
        form.InvokeMember("submit");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3184111, what is the goal behind this: GUI test automation, or [web-scrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)?

Comment: Scrapping pretty much. I've gotten to the point where now I can modify the data, etc BUT it does it after all the users cycle through. Right so lets say all my users get put in, at the end it'll open like 40 instances of the WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted but I need it to do each one between users, not all at once at the end.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21021055/1768303) for a sample code which you can adapt for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you want to use it for testing or not but you can use Coded Ui Test for that. You can record the actions and then generate code for that and then run it repeatedly after that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: I'm talking about a web form. Maybe I should have specified that. My fault.

Comment: I'm not trying to verify or test anything. I have a web page that I want this program to be able to contact and login to then retrieve the url on the next page.

Comment: The idea behind the answer isn't that you need to test or verify anything, but that the coded ui test framework will provide code that automates each action which seems to be what you're asking for

Comment: Will this let me do the same for HTML pages? I don't see anything explaining that on MSDN.

Comment: Yes. You can record the steps using MTM first and then generate the code. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286608(v=vs.100).aspx