# C# WebBrowser HTMLElement.InvokeMember("click") not working within <form> tag

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a C# form application which automates some user behaviour by clicking through buttons, links, forms, etc in a WebBrowser. Everything worked fine, im using InvokeMember("click") without problem on several buttons and links, but now i'm stuck with one click.

I'm struggling for days, and i have tried several tips, but nothing worked yet. The HTML code with the form basically looks like the following:

```
<form name="shipsChosen" id="shipsChosen" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/index.php?page=2">

<li class="off" id="button1">
            <div class="buildingimg"><a  href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <input id="ship_1"/>
</li>

<li class="off" id="button2">
            <div class="buildingimg"><a  href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <input id="ship_2"/>
</li>

<li class="off" id="button3">
            <div class="buildingimg"><a  href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <input id="ship_3"/>
</li>

</form>

<a  href="javascript:void(0);" onClick='setMaxIntInput();' id="sendall"></a>
<a id="continue" class="off" href="" onClick="trySubmit(); return false;"><span>Submit</span></a>
```

**What i want, is to click on the link with "sendall" ID, and then click on the link with "continue" ID.**

I have already tried the followings, but none of them worked. Nothing happens:

```
HtmlElement AllShips = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sendall");
AllShips.RaiseEvent("onclick");
AllShips.InvokeMember("click");
```

I have also tried to put some value into the input fields, but it's not works neither:

```
HtmlElement Input= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ship_202");
Input.Focus();
Input.InnerText = "ship_1";
```

It's very interesting to me, since althought it's not working when i run this without any user interaction in my C# form application with WebBrowser, **BUT** if i click once by myself in the WebBrowser, and run the click codes above, it works. But it's not automation right..?

Anyone experienced similar problems like this? The only difference i found between the working clicks and in this, is the  in the HTML.

*More:*
I'm using Internet Explorer 11 FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for the WebBrowser.
The page is fully loaded.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643

Answer (score 0):

Try letting your application pause before invoking the clicks and between them, because the page may still be busy with some earlier processes.
you can use a timer control for that effect.