# C# Get HTML generated by Javascript in a .Net Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing, console-application, webbrowser-control

I have to write a **Console Application** that **grap and parse data from a website**.

Unluckly, the website uses some kind of Javascript framework to compose the page.

So what I need to do is get the HTML once time the page is rendered by Javascript.

This is just the first step, my second step is to navigate the website to collect data from different page but... Unluckly the pages that I have to parse does not have Urls, but they are loaded from Javascript too...

Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks to support
Dario

Comment: That is rough. Many such websites and frameworks start loading content after DocumentComplete fires which gives you no way of knowing when they actually finish loading everything.

Comment: Yes, but I think to have came to a possible solution...
Have a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930414/how-to-dynamically-generate-html-code-using-nets-webbrowser-or-mshtml-htmldocu/20934538#20934538
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044659/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-form-submit-not-working-using-invokememberclick/19063643#19063643

I think these threads could help...