# How to access controls inside a dynamic iframe?

Tags: .net, iframe, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate the access to a website using .net and the webbrowser control.

Everything went well until I came across this :

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__blackout" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

There are controls inside this iframe I have to manipulate ...
Is there a way to access those controls using the .net webbrowser control ? and how can I do it ?

Any advice or help on this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874259/1768303) should give you an idea of how to access a frame content with WinForms `WebBrowser`.

Comment: Thank you Noseratio, Now I can access every component.