# Set Auto width and height for converted HTML to Image using Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using these 2 Functions for generate Image from Html Code:

```
    public static void StartBrowser(string HtmlText)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
            webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;

            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser.DocumentText = HtmlText;

            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }
    static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        using (Bitmap bitmap =
            new Bitmap(
                webBrowser.Width=450,
                webBrowser.Height=1000))
        {
            webBrowser
                .DrawToBitmap(
                bitmap,
                new System.Drawing
                    .Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));

            string imgfile = "fileimg" + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + ".jpg";
            bitmap.Save(path + "/images/" + imgfile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            OrderDetailRepeatedImage = path + "/images/" + imgfile;

        }
        Application.ExitThread();

    }
```

The Issue that I am trying to fix is the previous code to generate an image using bitmap with specific width and height.

**How I can Make this function work by setting automatic width and height as the given html code, because some times the given html is more than the given dimensional?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [WebBrowser Html Document to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741246/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi I'm not using a url web, I am using a dummy html to generate an inage using bitmap

Comment: You're using a WebBrowser Control to render HTML content. That's all that matters. Read the notes in that post.