# Error when trying to log into website c#

Tags: c#, twitter, getelementbyid

I'm trying to login twitter mobile version in c# using getelementbyid. but when i invoke the click of the login button i get the following error. " Object reference not set to an instance of an object." here is the code im using. any help would be amazing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[username_or_email]").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[password]").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signupbutton").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error? If you're not sure, try using a debugger.

Comment: It's the very last line where the login button is clicked

Comment: Are you sure that `signupbutton` is the actual ID of the element?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `Document` has fully loaded first, so make use of the the `DocumentCompleted` event available to the `WebBrowser`.

Add the `DocumentCompleted` event handler somewhere (in the constructor or form load, depending on the nature of your project)

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //An example place to add this event handler.
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Document_Complete);
}

private void Document_Complete(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[username_or_email]").InnerText = textBox1.Text;
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[password]").InnerText = textBox2.Text;
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signupbutton").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

`DocumentCompleted` can fire many times, in which case see the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328835/why-is-webbrowser-documentcompleted-firing-twice) to help.

[DocumentComplete documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Aside, there is no need to call `.ToString()` on the `TextBoxes` `Text` property, it's already a string.